# Pagination work! But title still says "Page Not Found"

Tags: pagination

I'm using the following code:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts('posts_per_page=3&&paged='.$paged);
```

and then

```
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
```

As per wordpress codex - which works fine except on page 2 onwards the title in the browser says "Page Not Found | Blog" which is odd, because it is there, and everything else works fine!

The posts display as they should, all the post titles display and link through to the correct posts.

It's not a major problem, because it's working. But I just wondered if anyone knew why this was happening. Pagination always seems to throw me off anyway...

Comment: If you'd like to see the site for yourself it's here: http://www.creativecollective.biz/blog/

Comment: I don't see any "Page Not Found" message.

Comment: [read this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts) and then [read this.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

Comment: Thanks @Milo - this also caused a problem with the categories displaying, so rewriting the loop fixed that too. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same problem. Can you please share the solution? Thanks.